# What's the word to describe changing something wildly?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Say a company bought the copyright of published book and turned it into a TV show, but the ethos as well as plot is wholly disparate from the original book. So what can I say the screen writer did to the book instead of "changing the storyline?"

Answer (score 1):

The term  "*not faithful*" or even "*unfaithful*" is usual in the domain of discussion relative to scripts and their sources. Note that the corresponding noun is "fidelity", not "faithfulness" (true to fact, true to the original"); reading of the article below shows 75 occurrences of "fidelity" and 0 of "faithfulness"; see also this  [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faithfulness+of+the+film%2Cfidelity+of+the+film&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3#).

> [The Value of Fidelity in Adaptation](https://academic.oup.com/bjaesthetics/article/58/1/89/4838369)
> In this sense *Troy* seems faithful to the *Iliad*, whereas *O Brother, Where Art Thou?* can seem unfaithful to the *Odyssey*.

*Example*

- The screenwriter produced a script totally unfaithful to the book.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and external links! it's spectacularly helpful.